# Merge two SELECT queries with different ORDER BY

Tags: sql, t-sql, union-all

I have a Story table, and I need the following query:
- first 6 rows sorted by distance (I calculate it)
- next rows are sorted by TIME property descending

```
declare @profileID int
set @profileID = 6

declare @longitude float
set @longitude = 17.6009169090776

declare @latitude float
set @latitude = 46.9548404806283

SELECT
        first.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT top 6
                    [dbo].[Story].*,
                    SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - [dbo].[Story].[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - [dbo].[Story].[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
                FROM
                    [dbo].[Follow]
                LEFT JOIN
                    [dbo].[Story]
                    ON
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Followed] = [dbo].[Story].[ProfileID]
                WHERE
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Follower] = @ProfileID and
                    [dbo].[Story].IsDraft = 0
                ORDER BY 
                    [DistanceFromUser] asc
            ) first

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            last.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
                    [dbo].[Story].*,
                    SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - [dbo].[Story].[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - [dbo].[Story].[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
                FROM
                    [dbo].[Follow]
                LEFT JOIN
                    [dbo].[Story]
                    ON
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Followed] = [dbo].[Story].[ProfileID]
                WHERE
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Follower] = @ProfileID and
                    [dbo].[Story].IsDraft = 0
                **ORDER BY 
                    Time desc**
            ) last
```

My problem is the second query. It not sorts the records after the 6'th row descending by the TIME property, it sorts as ascending.

thnx

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll eat your hat if it isn't SQL Server.

Comment: Assign an arbitrary group identifier to your 2 groups and sort by it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT
        first.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT top 6
                    [dbo].[Story].*,
                    SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - [dbo].[Story].[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - [dbo].[Story].[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
               ,1 as ord
                FROM
                    [dbo].[Follow]
                LEFT JOIN
                    [dbo].[Story]
                    ON
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Followed] = [dbo].[Story].[ProfileID]
                WHERE
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Follower] = @ProfileID and
                    [dbo].[Story].IsDraft = 0
                ORDER BY 
                    [DistanceFromUser] asc
            ) first

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            last.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
                    [dbo].[Story].*,
                    SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - [dbo].[Story].[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - [dbo].[Story].[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
               ,row_number() over(order by Time desc) as ord
                FROM
                    [dbo].[Follow]
                LEFT JOIN
                    [dbo].[Story]
                    ON
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Followed] = [dbo].[Story].[ProfileID]
                WHERE
                    [dbo].[Follow].[Follower] = @ProfileID and
                    [dbo].[Story].IsDraft = 0
                **ORDER BY 
                    Time desc**
            ) last
```

**My try (example)**

```
declare @ta as table 
(
    id int
    ,na varchar(100)
    ,sal numeric(18,2)
)

insert into @ta( id,na,sal) values (1,'aa',10)
insert into @ta( id,na,sal) values (3,'bb',100)
insert into @ta( id,na,sal) values (2,'c',5)
insert into @ta( id,na,sal) values (4,'dd',50)

select * from
(select top 2 * , 1 as ord from @ta order by id) as f
union all
select * from (select top 100 percent * , row_number() over(order by sal desc) ord from @ta order by sal desc
) as tt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result set ordered in a particular way, then the *outermost* `SELECT` needs an `ORDER BY`.

You can control the ordering by including multiple keys in the outer `ORDER BY`.  If I'm reading the query correctly, the only difference is the `order by`, so put the logic for the queries in a CTE:

```
WITH sf as (
       SELECT s.*,
              SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - s.[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - s.[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
        FROM [dbo].[Follow] f LEFT JOIN
             [dbo].[Story] s
             ON f.[Followed] = s.[ProfileID]
        WHERE f.[Follower] = @ProfileID and
              s.IsDraft = 0
       )
SELECT sf.*
FROM ((SELECT TOP (6) sf.*, 1 as ord
       FROM sf
       ORDER BY [DistanceFromUser] ASC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP (6) sf.*, 2 as ord
       FROM sf
       ORDER BY Time DESC
      ) 
     ) sf
ORDER BY ord,
         (CASE WHEN ord = 1 THEN DistanceFromUser END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN ord = 2 THEN Time END) DESC;
```

You can also do this with window functions:

```
WITH sf as (
       SELECT s.*,
              SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - s.[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - s.[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
        FROM [dbo].[Follow] f LEFT JOIN
             [dbo].[Story] s
             ON f.[Followed] = s.[ProfileID]
        WHERE f.[Follower] = @ProfileID and
              s.IsDraft = 0
       )
SELECT sf.*
FROM (SELECT sf.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DistanceFromUser) as seqnum_d,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time DESC) as seqnum_t
       FROM sf
      ) 
     ) sf
WHERE seqnum_d <= 6 OR seqnum_t <= 6
ORDER BY ord,
         (CASE WHEN seqnum_d <= 6 THEN DistanceFromUser END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN seqnum_t <= 6 THEN Time END) DESC;
```

Your version could include the same row twice.  This version will not duplicate rows that are in the top 6 for both conditions.

Comment: I need the first 6 rows to be ordered by distance ascending and from the 7'th row by Time property

Comment: @Wasyster . . . That is what these queries do.

Comment: Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Line 10 is: WITH as sf (

Comment: Error in both queries

Answer (score 0):

So I ended with next solution thnx to everyone

```
WITH TempTable as 
(
    SELECT [dbo].[Story].*,
        SQRT( POWER(@Longitude - [dbo].[Story].[Longitude], 2) + POWER(@Latitude - [dbo].[Story].[Latitude], 2)) as [DistanceFromUser]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Follow] 
        LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[Story]
        ON [dbo].[Follow].[Followed] = [dbo].[Story].[ProfileID]
    WHERE [dbo].[Follow].[Follower] = @ProfileID and
        [dbo].[Story].IsDraft = 0
)


SELECT
        first.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT top 6
                    *,
                    1 as ord
                FROM
                    TempTable
                ORDER BY 
                    [DistanceFromUser] asc
            ) first

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            last.*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
                    *,
                    row_number() over(order by Time desc) as ord
                FROM
                    TempTable
                ORDER BY 
                    Time desc
            ) last
```